# getting cell value from numpy dataframe using loc

Tags: python

This should be simple but it's baffling me:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[1,4,5],[7,12,3]],columns=["A","B","C"])

subdf = df[df['A'] == 1]
print(subdf)
```

As expected:

```
 subdf
   A  B  C
 0  1  2  3
 1  1  4  5
```

But

```
 oneline = subdf.loc[subdf['C'] == 5]
 print ("One Line:")
 print(oneline['B'])
```

yields me:

```
 1    4
 Name: B, dtype: int64
```

I've tried a few ways to extract that '4' and keep getting keyerrors:

```
print(oneline['B'].at[0])

Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2898, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1032, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1039, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

Tried digging through the .loc() documentation but I've not found the answer. Any thoughts?

Comment: The line `oneline['B'].values[0]` should work as suggested in coments. We are doing `oneline['B'].values` because `oneline['B']` is of type `pands.Series` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
 oneline = subdf.loc[subdf['C'] == 5]
 print ("One Line:")
 print(oneline['B'].values[0])
```